# I use switch statement to include specific file but it includes the "default" also

Tags: php, include, switch-statement

Here's my code

```
    <?php
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
    switch ($id) {
        default:include_once('default.php');
        break;
        case 'actiune':include('jocuri/actiune/index.php');
        break;
        case 'aventura':include('jocuri/aventura/index.php');
        break;
     }
     ?>
    <!--games-->
     <?php
     $game = isset($_GET['game']) ? $_GET['game'] : '';
     switch ($game) {
         case 'nz':include('jocuri/actiune/ninja-vs-zombie/index.php');
         break;
         case 'aventura':include('/jocuri/aventura/index.php');
         break;
      }
      ?>
```

So when I try to acces case 'nz' from  it also includes default from the top part. So how can i do to include only the 'nz' case?

Answer (score 4):

Try moving the default statement to the bottom of the first switch statement. A switch statement goes straight down each case path, hence the need for the break keyword. The default case will always execute in the case no matter what. Putting it at the bottom will ensure it will only get executed when the cases fail.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you would like to ignore 'top part' (including file by *id*) when *game* parameter is provided.
Try to add IF statement to execute first switch-statement only if *game* is not provided (or not matched with your provided cases *['aventura', 'nz']*)

Moreover you can do something like that:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
$game = isset($_GET['game']) ? $_GET['game'] : '';

$games = array('nz' => 'jocuri/actiune/ninja-vs-zombie/index.php',
               'aventura' => '/jocuri/aventura/index.php');

$ids = array('actiune' => 'jocuri/actiune/ninja-vs-zombie/index.php',
             'aventura' => '/jocuri/aventura/index.php');

if (array_key_exists($game, $games))
{
  include($games[$game]);
}
else if (array_key_exists($id, $ids))
{
  include($ids[$id]);
}
else include('default.php');
```

Comment: Where and how can i do that?

Comment: I have included the source-code to explain my idea in better way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
switch ($id) {

    case 'actiune':include('jocuri/actiune/index.php');
    break;
    case 'aventura':include('jocuri/aventura/index.php');
    break;
   default:include_once('default.php');
    break;
 }
 ?>
<!--games-->
 <?php
 $game = isset($_GET['game']) ? $_GET['game'] : '';
 switch ($game) {
     case 'nz':include('jocuri/actiune/ninja-vs-zombie/index.php');
     break;
     case 'aventura':include('/jocuri/aventura/index.php');
     break;
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

(I did try to add this as a comment to osulerhia's answer but couldn't and figured it might answer the posters question if I've read it correctly).

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly and if osulerhia's answer above is what you're looking for.

You're expecting two separate GET variables ("id" and "game") and if the game variable is "nz" you don't want to show the default from the switch statement you're using for "id"?

If that's right then you need to add some sort of logic to how you want your switch statements to play out. You then also need to consider though whether you want either of the others to show if "nz" is the value of "game". Your logic (written plainly) is currently:

```
Is the id variable "actiune" -> include a file

Is the id variable "aventura" -> include a file

Is the id variable anything else -> include the default file

Is the game variable "nz" -> include a file

Is the game variable "aventura" -> include a file
```

As you can see both of your switches are completely separate, you need to decide what you want to display and when you want to display it, for example, if you wanted everything to work as above but to not display ANYTHING from the first switch if the value of the game variable is "nz" then you could wrap it in an if statement like:

```
if((isset($_GET['game']) && $_GET['game'] != "nz") || (!isset($_GET['game']))) { *your original switch statement* }
```

Comment: So i have a header and a menu on the index page that is always displayed, next i access those variables from the menu. If i click actiune it includes a actiune.php file let's say, that contains another link that calls another variable named 'nz' and when it's called it includes the default case from the switch statement. I could delete the default case but it's the content of my index page that needs to be displayed:)